# Redshift varchar column time convert to 12 hours format

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a varchar column in redshift table where the time is stored in 24 hours format, e.g, `17:00`, I want to query the table and convert the format to 12 hours format showing AM or PM in time. When I test like `to_char('17:00'::time,'HH12:MI AM')` it works fine but when I put column name in place of hardcoded value querying the table,

```
SELECT to_char(prepoll_start::time,'HH12:MI AM') 
FROM votecast.poll_hours AS ph 
WHERE ph.prepoll_start is not null 
  and state = 'AL' 
  AND tab_elec_type = 'primary'
```

It won't work, gives an error

> Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;

Postgres version is 8.0.2

Please let me know what am doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

First I had to create a timestamp value out of the time available. Then fetch the time in a 12 hour format.

```
select to_char( to_timestamp('1900-01-01 '||prepoll_start||':00' ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') , 'HH12:MI AM') 
from votecast.poll_hours;
```

Comment: Yeah that's i know, but can this be achieved without appending date to the time?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift does not support a `TIME` data type.

See: [Datetime Types - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html)

However, you are correct that it seems to support `TIME` for non-table related operations.

I tried playing around with string manipulation but was unable to get beyond the error you experienced. I think it is because `TIME` is recognized on the leader node, but fails to run on the compute nodes. (This is similar to the behaviour of `time_series()`.)

Thus, you won't be able to use the `TIME` data type for anything that relies on table data.